# Pandas timedelta subtraction returns different values when operands are swapped

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have two `pd.Timestamp` objects:

```py
t1 = pd.Timestamp(2022-11-02 10:44:22.700000)
t2 = pd.TImestamp(2022-11-02 10:44:22.760000)
```

Now I want to get the timedelta for those two values.
If I do it like this:

```py
t2 - t1
```

I get `Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.060000')`, which is the expected behaviour,
but If I do:

```py
t1 - t2
```

I get `Timedelta('-1 days +23:59:59.940000')`, which seems a bit weird as the difference between both is still 0.6 seconds.

Can I avoid this behavior somehow? I don't want to check which is the bigger value before getting the Timedelta.

Comment: are you just looking for the text to be different? The results are the same right other than their textual representation.?

Comment: @JonSG nope they aren't I wanted to check if the result is < Timedelta("1 minute") and for the first result it returns true and for the second false. So it's not just textual representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `abs` (absolute value) to get the magnitude of the difference:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> t1 = pd.Timestamp('2022-11-02 10:44:22.700000')
>>> t2 = pd.Timestamp('2022-11-02 10:44:22.760000')
>>> t2 - t1
Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.060000')
>>> t1 - t2
Timedelta('-1 days +23:59:59.940000')
>>> abs(t1 - t2)
Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.060000')
```

Comment: Now I feel so stupid :D. Thought, this only works for native python types.

Comment: Don't feel bad! `abs()` can actually work on any type which implements `__abs__()` . Some details from the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs
You can tell that the developers of `pd.Timestamp` spent the effort to implement absolute value for that data type.